# Android Facebook SDK - How can I stay logged in after a reboot

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I'm using the facebok SDK and a BootReceiver which is triggered when the boot sequence has completed:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
```

I presume that a user is logged in when:

```
public boolean isLoggedIn() {
    return AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null;
}
```

However, this always returns as false.

How can I resume a user's session and keep them logged in after a reboot? This needs to be done within the boot receiver to check if a user was previously logged in, and provide access to:

```
Profile.getCurrentProfile()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to logOut before perform a login inside the broadcastReceiver. This will ensure you have the user logged in

```
    LoginManager loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();
    loginManager.logOut();
    loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(...);

    loginManager.registerCallback(...);
```

Comment: logInWithReadPermissions requires an Activity or Fragment?

Comment: Yes, you are right, a Fragment or Activity is required for this method

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

It seems to work if I set up an Asynchronous call to refresh the access token, then check if the user was logged in:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        AccessToken.refreshCurrentAccessTokenAsync(new AccessToken.AccessTokenRefreshCallback() {
            @Override
            public void OnTokenRefreshed(AccessToken accessToken) {
                System.out.println("Refresh succeed");
                AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(accessToken);
                if (isLoggedIn()) {
                    System.out.println("User is logged in");
                    doCoolStuffHere();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("User is not logged in");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void OnTokenRefreshFailed(FacebookException exception) {
                System.out.println("Refresh failed");
            }
        });
    }
}
```